# Angular JS plugin for WebStorm 7

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am following the plugin [link](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971?pr=). I have followed these steps after installing the plugin.

- Goto the WebStorm File->Settings->IDE Settings->Plugins.
- Click Install plugin from disk and select the zip files.
- Restart the WebStorm.

After opening the WebStorm, I am unable to type anything in the IDE (HTML and JS files, any of them).

I prefer doing it manually.

Can any one pour in your experiences and suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes plugins accessible via the download method may not work. To start clean, you should delete that plugin you downloaded, including any directory under [`plugins`](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) that it might have created.

Then, go to Settings -> Plugins -> Browser Repositories, and install AngularJS that way. It's a standard plugin from JetBrains.

Comment: When I click on Browse Repositories, "List of plugins unavailable, Connection failed : connect" message appears. So, I wnated to do it in  a manual way. Any clue why this is happening? I work in a company where outside URL's are not permitted. So skipped Browse Repo.

Comment: @MBK For whatever reason, AngularJS plugin when installed from a zip does not have/install all dependencies (some files got missing and you are unable to type because of that). Using "Settings | Plugins | Browse Repositories..." will install it properly. As for "blocking direct URLs in your company" -- see if you can use your company proxy (your can configure it in Settings as well). Other that: install it on another (home) computer and see if copying plugin files over will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://jetbrains.zendesk.com/entries/38945603-JavaScript-can-t-edit-files-after-installing-AngularJS-plugin for explanation/fix

Problems like this usually occur when installing plugin from disk if you extract the downloaded archive and select the plugin `.jar` when installing instead of using the downloaded zip without unpacking it.

Comment: Link only answers are a no go.